# Need help to solve this linear differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given differential equation:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = 30 - \dfrac{20y}{800+30t}$$.

Show that the solution to the given equation is

$$y(t) = C(80 + 3t)^{-2/3} + 18t + 480$$

[image]

Comment: Your other, now deleted, question was better at the end with the corrected formula. What problems do you have applying the standard solution process for order 1 linear DE?

Comment: I voted to close because the OP did not even do the tiring work of writing the answer by him/herself

Comment: Whenever I apply general equation to my solution it doesn't get the answer same as one in the photo.

Comment: Sorry I tried to write it in but I can't get it right. It's my first time here.

Comment: First order linear ODE, just solve it using an integrating factor...

Comment: The general equation I've used is: y(integrating factor)= \int Q(x)(integrating factor) dt + C

Comment: Here is a resource for mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You are more likely to get useful help on this site if you explain what you've tried so far, where you are stuck. Otherwise you are likely to get downvoted or have your question closed.

Comment: @JaydeeRamos Well, you are given $y(t) = \dots$ To show it is a solution, simply substitute it into the ODE and verify that $\mathrm{LHS} = \mathrm{RHS}$. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I saw your attempt in the comment section. Let's go thru this slowly.

We have
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 30 - \frac{20y}{800+30t}$$

Let's move the terms around to get
$$\frac{dy}{dt} +\frac{20}{800+30t}\cdot y= 30$$
which is just
$$\frac{dy}{dt} +\frac{2}{80+3t}\cdot y= 30$$
We know that ODE of the form
$$\frac{dy}{dt}+P(t)y=Q(t)$$
has the integrating factor
$$\exp\left(\int P(t) \ dt\right)$$
In this case, we have 
$$P(t)=\frac{2}{80+3t}$$
so our IF is
$$\exp\left(\int \frac{2}{80+3t} \ dt\right)$$
The integration is simple so you should be able to do on your own. Eventually, we have the IF
$$\exp\left(\frac{2}{3}\ln(80+3t)\right)=(80+3t)^{\frac23}$$
So
$$\frac{d}{dt}((80+3t)^{\frac23}y)=30(80+3t)^{\frac23}$$
Then
$$(80+3t)^{\frac23}y=\int 30(80+3t)^{\frac23} \ dt$$
We get
$$(80+3t)^{\frac23}y=6(80+3t)^{\frac53}+C$$
Divide $(80+3t)^{\frac23}$ through, we have
$$y=6(80+3t)^{1}+C(80+3t)^{-\frac{2}{3}}$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The given differential equation

\begin{align}
& \dfrac{dy}{dt} = 30 - \dfrac{20y}{800 + 30 t} = 30 - \dfrac{2y}{80 + 3 t} \\
\implies & \dfrac{dy}{dt} + \dfrac{2}{80 + 3 t} \, y = 30 \\
\implies & \dfrac{dy}{dt} + P y = Q. \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $P = \frac{2}{80 + 3 t}$ and $Q = 30$.

The integration factor $I$ can be calculated as 
\begin{align}
 I & = \exp \left[ \int P \, dt \right] = \exp \left[ \int \dfrac{2}{80 + 3 t} \, dt\right] \\
& = \exp \left[ \dfrac{2}{3} \log (80 + 3t)\right] = (80 + 3t)^{2/3}. \tag{2}
\end{align}

Multiplying (1) by the integration factor yields, 
\begin{align}
& (80 + 3t)^{2/3} \dfrac{dy}{dt} + \dfrac{2}{80 + 3t} (80 + 3t)^{2/3} y = 30 (80 + 3t)^{2/3} \\
\implies & (80 + 3t)^{2/3} \dfrac{dy}{dt} + 2 (80 + 3t)^{-1/3} y = 30 (80 + 3t)^{2/3}. \tag{3}
\end{align}

Integrating (3) yields, 
\begin{align}
& (80 + 3t)^{2/3} y = 6(80 + 3t)^{5/3} + C \\
\implies & y = 6 \times (80 + 3t) + C (80 + 3t)^{-2/3} \\
\implies & \boxed{y = C (80 + 3t)^{-2/3} + 18 t + 480}
\end{align}